# No files have been transferred after rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

When I ran 'rsync' in the following way, no file has been transferred?!

```
rsync -rv -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/user/.ssh/myrsd.pem" /cygdrive/c/user/local/temp/somefolder root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/
```

terminal output:

> sending incremental file list
>
> sent 118 bytes  received 26 bytes  96.00 bytes/sec
>   total size is 1,560  speedup is 10.83

Answer (score 2):

rsync works only on deltas- meaning if a file already exists on destination folder, and it is identical to the file in the source - it won't be copied. only new/updated files will be transferred

so if all files are already there- rsync will have nothing to do

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the missing slash after the local folder - 'somefolder' in this case. It should be '/cygdrive/c/user/local/temp/somefolder/' instead of '/cygdrive/c/user/local/temp/somefolder'

In the former case the output shows no files after "sending incremental file list" while it will show the files transferred in the latter one.

> sending incremental file list
>   xx/xx/myfile

Comment: Not necessarily. The trailing slash determines whether or not the source directory name is included on the target